# tcl/tk: avoid error message about remove non existing file

Tags: tcl

In my Tcl/Tk script, there is one step to remove some txt file. 
I use:

```
exec rm file1.txt
```

But if the file dose not exist, then error message will come up which will block the script usage. 
What I want to do is remove the file if it exist, and if it does not exist, to skip the error. 
Is there a good way of doing this?

Ok, I find the answer: `file exists filename` works well for this case.

Comment: Actually, you're better off not using `file exists` to check before deleting; the file could be created or go away between the time that the check is done and when the delete happens. (It's a basic race condition.) Better to handle the error (or never throw it in the first place, as `file delete` does).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use

```
file delete file1.txt
```

where [trying to delete a non-existent file is not considered an error.](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm#M12)

Answer (score 0):

How to avoid having an error stop your program.

The "0th" solution is to use commands that don't raise errors. such as `glob -nocomplain` instead of just `glob`, or in this case `file delete file1.txt` as suggested by timrau.

In some cases it's impossible to prevent errors from being raised. In those cases you can choose from several strategies. Assume you need to call `mycmd`, and it might raise errors.

```
# Tcl 8.6
try mycmd on error {} {}

# Tcl 8.4 or later
catch mycmd
```

This invocation quietly intercepts the error and lets your program continue. This is perfectly acceptable if the error isn't important, e.g. when you attempt to discard a variable that might not exist (`catch {unset myvar}`).

You might want to take some action when an error is raised, such as reporting it to yourself (as an error message on `stderr` or in a message box, or in a log of some kind) or by dealing with the error somehow.

```
try mycmd on error msg {puts stderr "There was a problem: $msg"}

if {[catch mycmd msg]} {
    puts stderr "There was a problem: $msg"
}
```

You might want to take some action *only* if there was no error:

```
try {
    mycmd
} on ok res {
    puts "mycmd returned $res"
} on error msg {
    puts stderr "There was a problem: $msg"
}

if {[catch mycmd res]} {
    puts stderr "There was a problem: $res"
} else {
    puts "mycmd returned $res"
}
```

For instance, this invocation returns the contents of a file, or the empty string if the file doesn't exist. It makes sure that the channel is closed and the variable holding the channel identifier are destroyed in either case:

```
set txt [try {
    open $filename
} on ok f {
    chan read $f
} on error msg {
    puts stderr $msg
} finally {
    catch {chan close $f}
    catch {unset f}
}]
```

Documentation: [catch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/catch.htm), [chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm), [file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm), [glob](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/glob.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [try](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/try.htm)